# What's the best FREE CDN service available?

Tags: performance, free, cdn

It seems like using CDN is a best option to provide users a great browsing experience. But, plans of the major CDN providers seem costly. So, I would like to get used to the CDN thing before I subscribe to any paid plans. Please let me know if there is an 100% free CDN services.

Comment: what kind of content do you want to serve?

Comment: A mixure of all. Some media, code and few other things.

Comment: "What's the best" is impossible to answer, as it implies subjectivity rather than objectivity. You'd be best asking (in the future) the question as "Given my situation (x), what's the recommended (y)?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best solution is probably http://www.coralcdn.org or using [Google's App Engine](http://www.placona.co.uk/159/general-techie-stuff/speed-up-yor-website-part-2-the-free-cdn/).

It also depends on how much content you think will be downloaded from your site.  I know Amazon Cloud Front isn't free but it does only cost $.12 per GB per month in the US.  See pricing here, http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#pricing.

Comment: +1 for Amazon. It's so cheap, there's no reason not to.

Comment: CoralCDN is a research project hacked together by academics and hosted on PlanetLab. It is extraordinarily slow, and often doesn't respond at all. Don't use it for anything you care about. It's not monitored by anyone and barely works.The same is true of the other free "research" CDN, CobWeb (http://www.cob-web.org/). It's main page doesn't even come up most of the time.

Comment: @rmalayter- That is good to know.  It goes to show you get what you pay for.

Comment: A page that takes 3 seconds to load directly takes me 17secs with CoralCDN.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com), but I haven't found it very reliable (even as DNS).

Your best bet is Google App Engine; I'm very happy with it.
It's free for [reasonable amounts of traffic](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html).

Comment: I want to try cloudflare, why didn't you think it was reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the [Speedy Mirror](https://www.speedymirror.com) services. It's free.

Comment: I have used Speedy Mirror in the past, and it's great CDN. But since two months ago Speedy Mirror is offline :(